# How do I create an HTML select box with results from a PHP search through AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is some background: I have a text file that is broken down into context blocks. Each block has a header of a pattern "[header]".  So far, I have been able to create a php script that will search for these headers and generate a list of only the headers.

What I have not yet been able to figure out is how to supply these results to a web page that will take this list and generate a drop-down/select box with the list as options.  Here is the php script:

```
    <?php
    $theList = array();
    $theInFile = 'extensions.conf';
    $theLine = '';
    $theReturnString = '';

    $inFile=fopen($theInFile, 'r') or exit('Unable to open file.');
    while(!feof($inFile))
    {   $theLine = fgets($inFile);
        $theLine = (string)$theLine;

        //  Is it a context header?
        //  Check for the presence of a '[', then the position of '['
        //  This method is used due to STRPOS returning ZERO if not found, 
        //  which is the position we are looking for.
        $x = strstr($theLine, '[');
        if ($x != '')
        {   $y = strpos($theLine, '[');
        if ($y == 0)
        {   // Only the context name itself is wanted.
            // If there is anything after the ']', strip it.

            $end = strlen($theLine);
            $tBracket = strpos($theLine, ']') + 1;

                if($end != $tBracket)
                $theLine = substr($theLine, 0, $tBracket);

            $theReturnString = $theReturnString.$theLine.'~';
        }
        }
    }
    fclose($inFile);

    echo $theReturnString;

    ?>
```

The following HTML page is as far as I have gotten.  It will at least get the return string separated into a list of headers, but I am at a loss as to how to get that list into a select / drop-down box:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form id="StartingPage" action="GetList.php" method="post">
</form>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc()
    {   var xmlhttp;
        var received;

        //  Browser setup;
        //  IF - code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        //  ELSE - code for IE6, IE5
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        else
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        // Retreive the list
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {   var newString = new Array();
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {   received = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                received = received.split('~');

                for ( i = 0; i < received.length; i++ )
                    document.writeln(received[i] + '<br>');

                document.writeln('Done.<br>');  
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","GetList.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
</script>
```

And and all advice and critiques are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think it would be better if you parse your file with regular expressions for performance reasons.
Then, prefer JSON for the response, it will be easier for you to read it with Javascript. JSON is also a good choice because it allows you to easily change your script (adding items) without requiring to change the way to parse the responses from Ajax requests.

Following regex will search for contents between "[" and "]".

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('extensions.conf');
preg_match_all('~\[(.+)\]~Usmx', $content, $headers, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

echo json_encode($headers[1]);
```

Now, for the client side, we parse response with [JSON.parse()](http://caniuse.com/#search=json) method and put it into select box by creating option elements with document.createElement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="StartingPage" action="GetList.php" method="post">
            <select name="mySelectName" id="mySelectId"></select>
        </form>

        <script>
            function loadXMLDoc()
            {
                //  Browser setup;
                //  IF - code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                //  ELSE - code for IE6, IE5
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                else
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

                // Retreive the list
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                    {
                        var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelectId');
                        var headers = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                            var option = document.createElement('option');
                            option.setAttribute('value', i);
                            option.innerHTML = headers[i];
                            mySelect.appendChild(option);
                        }
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "GetList.php", true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

            loadXMLDoc();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question right, you need to display select with options from that array .. this should work :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form id="StartingPage" action="GetList.php" method="post">
</form>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc()
    {   var xmlhttp;
        var received;

        //  Browser setup;
        //  IF - code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        //  ELSE - code for IE6, IE5
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        else
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        // Retreive the list
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {   var newString = new Array();
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {   received = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                received = received.split('~');

                var select = document.createElement("select");
                select.setAttribute("name", "mySelect");
                select.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
                var option;
                for ( i = 0; i < received.length; i++ )
                {
                    /* create options elements */
                    option = document.createElement("option");
                    /* You can change i with received[i] if you need your options with values equal to displayed text */
                    option.setAttribute("value", i);
                    option.innerHTML = received[i];
                    select.appendChild(option);
                }
                // Append the select to the end of the body tag
                document.body.appendChild(select);
                // Or You can use something like this also
                // document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(select);
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","GetList.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
</script>
```